# How do I trigger a method to run after x seconds?

Tags: c#, timer

I am working on a C# Windows Forms application where I need the method to pause for 30 seconds until it continues on to the next line of code. I have tried `Thread.Sleep()` which wasn't suitable for this application and I've understood that I should use some sort of timer instead. I have searched a lot but I can't figure out how to implement timers.

My code is below and could anyone show me how I should implement the timer. I have made a comment on where I want the method to pause.

```
private void start_Vid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (video.State != StateFlags.Running)
    {
        viewport.Visible = true;
        video.Play();
    }

    //Here I want to wait 30 seconds until the next line of code is triggered

    viewport.Visible = false;
    viewport2.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    start_Webc(); 
    video2.Play();
}
```

Comment: Create a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: Why Thread.Sleep is not suitable for this app?

Comment: @SergeyS Thread.Sleep is rarely appropriate, except if you are explicitely on your own thread. In this case, it would block the UI completely, rendering the interface useless and interrupting the video.

Answer (score 35):

If your app is a .Net 4.5 application, then it's somewhat easier to use `Task`:

```
private async void start_Vid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (video.State != StateFlags.Running)
    {
        viewport.Visible = true;
        video.Play();
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

    viewport.Visible = false;
    viewport2.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    start_Webc();
    video2.Play();
}
```

Comment: Good answer for future visitors. +1

Answer (score 14):

Task.Delay is not available on .NET 4.0, but you can start task, which will just sleep for 30 seconds, and later you can continue on UI thread again:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000))
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
         viewport.Visible = false;
         viewport2.Visible = true;
         pictureBox1.Visible = true;
         start_Webc(); 
         video2.Play();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Great answer as I commented. +1

Comment: Timer is also good, because `Tick` event will be executed on UI thread. Also thus OP code does not use local variables, then you can put timer on form, set interval, subscribe to event. And all code will be simple like `timer1.Start()`;

Comment: One problem I have thought of with this solution - I assume all those  vars (`viewport`,`pictureBox` etc) are UI items and you might need to `Invoke` to them - doesnt `ContinueWith` execute on its own Thread?

Comment: @Jamiec that's why I continue with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` :)

Comment: Im going to test this later tonight but I'm confident I can get this to work! Fantastic that so many people are prepared to help out a stranger! What would n00b programmers like me do without sites as stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay( 60 * 1000 ).ContinueWith( (_) => StartVoid() );
```

Answer (score 6):

At class level define an instance of `Timer` (There are a few classes like this - for a winforms app you should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`)

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
```

Then in your method add lines to handle its tick and start it:

```
private void start_Vid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (video.State != StateFlags.Running)
    {
        viewport.Visible = true;
        video.Play();
    }

    myTimer.Tick += (o,ea) => {    
        viewport.Visible = false;
        viewport2.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        start_Webc(); 
        video2.Play();
        myTimer.Stop();
    }
    myTimer.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
    myTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Undeleted now :) just verified if Delay available on .Net 4.0

Answer (score 4):

We can do that using Task from

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
                Method1()));
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

There would also be a way with reactive extensions:

```
Observable.Return("Delayed").Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Subscribe(val => Console.WriteLine("Executing delayed"));
```

Answer (score 0):

case WPF..

- WPF extension:

```cs
public static partial class WpfUtils
{
    public static void RunAfter(double seconds, Action action)
    {
        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher == null)
            return;
        var myTimer = new DispatcherTimer(
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            Application.Current.Dispatcher)
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)
        };
        myTimer.Tick += (_, _) =>
        {
            action?.Invoke();
            myTimer.Stop();
        };
        myTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

- Usage:

```cs
WpfUtils.RunAfter(3, () =>
{
    // some code
    Console.WriteLine("Running after 3 seconds");
});
```

Note that this code will run on the UI thread.. on the other hand, if you go with methods from `Task` class, the delayed code will run on a background thread.

- Showcase:

```cs
Task.Delay(6 * 1000).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    // this will run in a background-thread
    var b = Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground;
    Debug.Assert(b);
    Console.WriteLine("3");
});

var timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
};
timer.Tick += (_, _) =>
{
    // this will run in the UI-thread
    var b = Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground;
    Debug.Assert(!b);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    timer.Stop();
};
timer.Start();

Console.WriteLine("1");

// output
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

1. Drag a `Timer` to your form and set `Enabled=False` and `Interval=YOUR_DELAY`
2. Double click on the timer and put your function inside it. at the last line, add `Timer1.Enabled = false` !
3. When you want to start the delay, like after a click or etc, Activate the timer by `Timer1.Enabled = true`
4. Done!

So when you click on button or sth, the timer start and after running your code, it will get disabled again.